# PHP merge array but only second array is random

Tags: php

I have two array:

```
$divs = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six');
$ads = array ('Ad1', 'Ad2', 'Ad3');
```

I want merge like this:

```
$mix_divs = array_merge($divs, $reklama);
```

But, **$divs** must stay in same places and between this places I need to add random **$ads** array.

```
shuffle($ads);
```

Final input must be something like this:

```
$mix_divs = array('One','Two','Ad2','Three','Four','Ad3','Five','Six','Ad1');
```

or

```
 $mix_divs = array('Ad2','One','Two','Ad1','Three','Four','Five','Ad3','Six');
```

$ads must be random inserted.

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: if you want the elements to stay in place, you're not looking for array_merge, you want to use array_splice to inject the $ads array elements.

Comment: You have not completely defined your question: Are there always six divs and three ads? Do you always want two divs between two ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just insert each ad in a random position in divs:

```
$divs = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six');
$ads = array ('Ad1', 'Ad2', 'Ad3');

$newArray = array_merge($divs);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ads); $i++) {
    $position = rand(0, count($newArray));
    array_splice($newArray, $position, 0, $ads[$i]);
}
```

I just tried to `print_r($newArray)` and it gave me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => One
    [1] => Two
    [2] => Three
    [3] => Ad2
    [4] => Four
    [5] => Ad1
    [6] => Five
    [7] => Ad3
    [8] => Six
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$divs = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six');
$ads  = array('Ad1', 'Ad2', 'Ad3');

shuffle($ads);
while ($ads) array_splice($divs, array_rand($divs), 0, array_pop($ads));

print_r($divs);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ad1
    [1] => One
    [2] => Two
    [3] => Ad3
    [4] => Three
    [5] => Four
    [6] => Five
    [7] => Ad2
    [8] => Six
)
```